# Reference books for the study of integral equations.

Tags: reference-request, integral-equations, reference-works

I've got "Integral equations" as the major subject this semester.I need to know what is most suitable reference book for  self-study of integral equations?How to study this subject effectively?

Any suggestions are heartly welcome,thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Integral equation and Boundary value problem** by M.D.Raisinghania can serve as a good introductory reference book.It is  good source of solved examples,theory and unsolved problems.

Study this book,you'll automatically understand how to study *Integral equations*.

Comment: :Thanks,atleast you answered:-).

Comment: @Picaso:Its mine pleasure...